# Function work only with first button. Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i write app on laravel 7. 
After writing the code for the lesson, its part responsible for deletion works only with the first position. The part responsible for changes - works on all positions. Please, help.

Example working edit code

```
public function edit(User $user)
{   

    if(Gate::denies('edit-users'))
    {return redirect(route('admin.users.index'));}

    $roles = Role::all();

    return view('admin.users.edit')->with([
        'user' => $user,
        'roles' => $roles
    ]);
}
```

Example not working at all positions destroy

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{   
    if(Gate::denies('edit-users'))
    {return redirect(route('admin.users.index'));}

    $user->roles()->detach();
    $user->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
}
```

and example menu code

```
 <tbody>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray())}}</td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary float-left">Edit</a>
                        <form action="{{route('admin.users.destroy', $user)}}" method="POST" class="float-left">
                            @csrf
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Sure to delete {{ $user->name }}?')">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
```

Route-list
[image]

Comment: what does `first position` mean?

Comment: Work only with first position on menu, and ignore for another positions.

Comment: what happened when you delete other positions?

Comment: If i click on other buttons, i have confirm-window, and nothing after that. No deleting, no actions at all

Comment: You never close your form. That can confuse it

Comment: Close form, but problem not solved

Comment: is it even hitting the server when you are trying to delete other positions? can you do `dd(user->id)` in the `destroy` method and what's the result?

Comment: I add `dd($user)`, and that works only for first button. Others again show me confim window and nothing after

Comment: In the link you use `route('admin.users.edit', $user->id)` but in the form `route('admin.users.edit', $user)` would making them match work?

Comment: @Larjadan That means is not submitting the form for others, can you share your js code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aynber and @apokryfos for solving my problem.

Edit my code like that, and it's begin working

```
<form action="{{route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST" class="float-left">
@csrf
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Sure to delete {{ $user->name }}?')">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Accept your own answer